# How to avoid multiple redirects in Nginx when removing www and shortening URLs

Tags: nginx, redirect, seo

I looked through many tutorials but cannot find the answer to my case.

I am moving my website to a non-www domain while also renaming and shortening URLs.
Below is my Nginx virtual conf structure:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private/key.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    return              301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private/key.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    # 400 redirects manually entered here: 
    location /long-url-1/ { return 301 https://example.com/short-url-1; }
    location /long-url-2/ { return 301 https://example.com/short-url-2; }
    # etc, other redirects continue 

}
```

The problem I currently have with the above redirect rules is if I enter the full long URL in the browser, like:

```
https://www.example.com/long-url-1/
```

I am redirected twice before I reach my destination URL:

```
301 https://www.example.com/long-url-1/
301 https://example.com/long-url-1/
200 https://example.com/short-url-1
```

Which is obviously bad for users and search engine bots.

I guess the possible solution could be to take my redirect rules and copy them into the first server block as well (right before the `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;`) But it doesn't work. I still get two redirects www => non-www => new-short-url.

How can I avoid having multiple redirects and send users straight to my destination URLs?

**EDIT**: *Please note, I still want to redirect users from www => non-www in case the requested URL is not found in my "manually entered list" of redirects, eg:*

```
https://www.example.com/some-new-url/ => 301 redirect => https://example.com/some-new-url/
```

Comment: Why do you get two redirects if you copy the rules into the first block? Either you did not test it after clearing the browser cache, or you left the `return` statement in the `server` block.

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, yes, I did leave the return statement since I still want to redirect all URLs that are not described in my "manual redirect list" to the non-www domain. I will add this information to the original question.

Comment: The naked return statement will take precedence and break all of your other rules. You need to wrap it inside the default `location` block: `location / { return ...; }`